# Laravel minify CSS and clear cache

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

I'm using this minification library to join and minify my CSS and JS: https://github.com/DevFactoryCH/minify

My problem is, when I deploy the changes to production, users still see the old version of the CSS, since the file name is the same. Now on any other website I would just use a version parameter (?v=1.0) to change the css version and force reload, but on laravel using minify, all I have is:

```
    {!! Minify::stylesheet([
        '/css/style.css', 
        '/css/responsive.css', 
        '/css/jquery.selectbox.css',
        '/css/calendar.css',
        ])->withFullUrl() !!}
```

So I can't really edit the file name or any arguments.

My question is: how can I force reload on my client's side without using a query string parameter?

Comment: Check out elixir - https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir doesn't require any other libraries and supports version numbering to avoid cache issues as long as you add the files to the views using {{ elixir('path to file') }}